# regarding SQL Query "LIKE"

Tags: sql

Why specifically '%' used in SQL for searching something with LIKE Query. Eg: If i want to search all the persons with name starting with word 's' why i have to write "LIKE 's%'" but not just write "LIKE 's'"

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: @SumanCodes . . . That is the definition of the syntax.

Comment: @OddmarDam Will learn and follow that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard character(%) is used to substitute one or more characters in a string. This is used to denote and display all other character which comes after the selected string in sql query. Because of that, we are using **like letter%** in sql query.